# What's the best way in Selenium WebDriver to wait for buttons to be enabled?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am creating an automated testing program with webdriverjs of an application where the 'Next' buttons are often disabled for a time, then enabled. The automation waits for the button to become enabled, then clicks the button.

The class of a button in particular toggles from : 'btn btn-next disabled' to 'btn btn-next'

I have come up with the following solution but wonder if there was a better way?

```
browser.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('nav a[class="btn btn-next"]')),
timeout, 'button still disabled after timeout').then(function() {
   browser.findElement(By.css('nav a[class="btn btn-next"]')).click();
});
```

Which seems to do the trick.

Originally my idea was to run function such as:

```
tryToClick = function(element){
  var classValue = element.getAttribute("class");
  isDisabled = classValue.search('disabled') !== -1 ? true : false;
  if(isDisabled){
    setTimeout(function () {
      tryToClick(element);
    }, 500);
  } else {
  element.click();
  }
}
```

However, methods such as search, split, contains, etc resulted in errors. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

Function name is `elementToBeClickable()`

Example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.css('nav a[class="btn btn-next"]')));
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Webdriver JS](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/) you can use [`until.elementIsDisabled`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html#elementIsDisabled) or [`until.elementIsEnabled`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/until.html#elementIsEnabled)

```
var theButton = driver.findElement(By.css('nav a[class="btn"));
driver.wait(until.elementIsDisabled(theButton)), 10000, 'element is still enabled, sorry.').then(function(){
   theButton.click();
});
```

But it looks like you are selecting an entire class of buttons, if so, make sure your iterate over them and click the one you want, or use css `nth-child();`

Answer (score 0):

I typically work in `Java` and `C#`, but there should be an equivalent option in `JS`. You will want to do an explicit wait using:

```
Until.ElementIsEnabled(<locator>)
```

If there isn't an equivalent to the above `wait..until`, you could resolve the issue by using `element.isEnabled() == false` in place of the `isDisabled` variable. In your code.